# How to test nth array element with Laravel fluent JSON testing

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I have implemented an API endpoint which returns a JSON array, and I want to test the values in say the 2nd element. Here is an example output - in my real data each array element has more attributes. I want to test attributes on different elements in the array. For example I might want to test the first_name attribute on the 2nd element.

```
[
  { "id" 23, "first_name": "Geri"},
  { "id" 25, "first_name": "Emma"},
  { "id" 46, "first_name": "Mel"}
]
```

Laravel fluent JSON testing allows you to test the nth element in a *nested* array using the following syntax

```
    $response->assertJson(fn (AssertableJson $json) =>
        $json->has('users', 3)
             ->has('users.1', fn (AssertableJson $json) =>
        ...
```

But my array is the root of the response. I can test the count and first element as follows but can't work out how to test a different element

```
   $response->assertJson(fn (AssertableJson $json) =>
        $json->has(3)
             ->first(fn (AssertableJson $json) =>
             ...
```

Is there any way to test a specific element other than the first using the fluent approach? Thanks

Comment: Would help to have a sample output added to the question and mention what are you trying to test in that sample.

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen I have added a simple example output

Comment: I believe you can test it using `$response->assertJsonFragment(['id' => 46]);`. I haven't tested it but I believe it should work. Let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your response is an array it will be prefixed with and index (just like a nested array). So simply use the index of the element you want to access.
In your case it would be something like this:

```
 $response->assertJson(fn (AssertableJson $json) =>
        $json->has(3)
             ->has('2', fn (AssertableJson $json) =>
                //assert something inside 2nd element in array
                 $json->where('first_name', 'Emma')
                      ->etc()
             )
        ...
```

Comment: Yes! I was looking exactly for this - struggled to find the syntax, but this is it!